# How to show date with correct time zone

Tags: notion-api

Is there a way for Notion to insert the dates from the API and respect the timezone set in the database? If I submit thru the API a date like `2000-01-02T00:00:00Z`, it shows up with “(UTC)” at the end in Notion instead of the EST time zone that I’ve set in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add the timezone offset to the end of your date like this:
"2000-01-02T00:00:00-05:00"

Answer (score 0):

I have two answers.

**1.** Just add your timezone like the example as follow.We can refer to this [official document](https://developers.notion.com/reference/property-value-object).

```json
{
  "Delivery Time": {
    "date": {
      "start": "2020-12-08T12:00:00Z",
      "time_zone": "America/New_York"
    }
  }
}
```

**2.**

```json
{
    "filter": {
        "or": [
            {
                "property": "My Time Property",
                "date": {
                    "before": "2023-10-15T12:00:00+08:00"   # replace your timezone
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "sorts": []
}
```

Here is an example about json.Just add timezone after real time.For example,time is `2023-3-15T12:00:00` and I want to use `HongKong(GMT+8)`,then I can replace it with `2023-3-15T12:00:00+08:00`.